# Is it possible to embed RSS feeds in PowerPoint slides?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, rss

I have a user asking if it's possible to embed an RSS feed inside a PowerPoint slide.

I said "yes", but now I doubt this, and I have yet to find a way to do it. Is it possible or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an add-on or third party utility it is possible I guess.
Like: http://www.labnol.org/software/insert-webpages-in-powerpoint-presentations/5108/